# Where to set aws configuration file in openwrt?

Tags: openwrt

Program to publish data using aws-sns is working in ubuntu 14.04 LTS.But the package for the same program does not work in openwrt environment.I know the problem is with configuration file,we have to set an aws configuration file in linux to ~/.aws/ in the file credentials.Where should i add this credentials if i use opewrt?And can i use amazon web services like sns without this configuration file?

Comment: I'm using OpenWRT AA  12.09 and I can find any package with the name is aws-sns. Is the package aws-sns released by OpenWRT ? which version of OpenWRT?
If the package awk-sns is your own package,you need to share more details about it.

Comment: I'm using Barrier Breaker openwrt buidld by myself.

Comment: I'm using Barrier Breaker openwrt buidld by myself. In this link"https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3D6U6WSFGOK2H/A-New-and-Standardized-Way-to-Manage-Credentials-in-the-AWS-SDKs" they have pointed out that linux users have to store credentials in ~/.aws/.So where is the location in openwrt to store these credentials?